# How to Connect Kafka to Postgres in Heroku

Tags: postgresql, heroku, apache-kafka, architecture, apache-kafka-connect

I have some Kafka consumers and producers running through my Kafka instance on my Heroku Cluster. I'm looking to create a data sink connector to connect Kafka to PosytgreSQL to put data FROM Kafka TO my heroku PostgreSQL instance. Pretty much like the [HeroKu docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/running-kafka-connectors-on-heroku), but one way.

I can't figure out the steps I need to take to achieve this.

The docs say to look at the [Gitlab](https://github.com/search?q=Apache%20Kafka%20connector) or [Confluence](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Ecosystem) Ecosystem page but i can't find any mention of Postgres in these.

Looking in the [Confluent Kafka Connectors library](https://www.confluent.io/hub/#postgres) there seems to something from Debezium but i'm not running Confluent.

The diagram in the [Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/running-kafka-connectors-on-heroku) mentions a JDBC connector? I found this [Postgres JDBC driver](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/), should I be using this?

I'm happy to create a consumer and update postgres manually as the data comes if that's what's needed, but I feel that Kafka to Postgres must be a common enough interface that there should be something out there to manage this?

I'm just looking for some high level help or examples to set me on the right path.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there :)

Bear in mind that Kafka Connect is part of Apache Kafka, and you get a variety of connectors. Some (e.g. Debezium) are community projects from Red Hat, others (e.g. JDBC Sink) are community projects from Confluent.

The [JDBC Sink connector](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-jdbc/current/sink-connector/index.html) will let you stream data from Kafka to a database with a JDBC driver - such as Postgres.

Here's an example configuration:

```json
{
    "connector.class"    : "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
    "key.converter"      : "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "connection.url"     : "jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/",
    "connection.user"    : "postgres",
    "connection.password": "postgres",
    "auto.create"        : true,
    "auto.evolve"        : true,
    "insert.mode"        : "upsert",
    "pk.mode"            : "record_key",
    "pk.fields"          : "MESSAGE_KEY"
}
```

Here's a [walkthrough](https://github.com/confluentinc/demo-scene/tree/master/kafka-to-database) and couple of videos that you might find useful:

- [Kafka Connect in Action: JDBC Sink](https://rmoff.dev/kafka-jdbc-video)
- [ksqlDB and the Kafka Connect JDBC Sink](https://rmoff.dev/ksqldb-jdbc-sink-video)

---

> Do i actually need to install anything

Kafka Connect comes with Apache Kafka. You need to [install the JDBC connector](https://rmoff.dev/install-kafka-connect-plugin).

> Do i actually need to write any code

No, just the configuration, similar to what I quoted above

> can i just call the Connect endpoint , which comes with Kafka,

Once you've [installed the connector](https://rmoff.dev/install-kafka-connect-plugin) you run Kafka Connect (a binary that ships with Apache Kafka) and then use the [REST endpoint to create the connector using the configuration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1EenWEm-5dg&t=213s)

Comment: Hi, thanks alot Robin. Trying to work out what I get for free here is tricky. 
Do i actually need to install anything / write any code or can i just call the Connect endpoint , which comes with Kafka, with a set up configuration like above?
Source: 
[Running Connectors on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/running-kafka-connectors-on-heroku#running-connectors-on-heroku) and 
[Dzone](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-use-kafka-connect-on-heroku-to-connect-two)

Comment: I've amended my answer